# url_for with target='_blank'

Tags: mojolicious

How to create a link with Mojolicious tag-helper `url_for` which opens in a new window/tab?
The result should be HTML-Code like `<a href="./intern/rba/list" target="_blank">RBA List</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%= link_to 'RBA-List' => url_for('list_rba'), target => '_blank'
```

Comment: Does this still work in the current version of Mojolicious? I've tried but had no luck.

Comment: At least here it works.


       `$ cpanm --info Mojolicious
       SRI/Mojolicious-9.33.tar.gz`

Comment: Working now, I had passed it as a param to url_for and not link_to. Whoops.